# Memory manipulation as a weapon: how could it be deployed most effectively?

Tags: weapons, politics, mind-control

A man with high political ambitions tries to rise to the top by using his special ability: memory manipulation.

How can he successfully use this ability to rise to the top of his kingdom/Empire?

**How the power works:**

The power affects the part of the brain in which memories are "saved". For it to work, the user needs either 1. eye contact with the target or 2. physical contact with the target.

The user can only work on one person at a time, meaning that mass hypnotizing is out of the question. But once the user has altered someone's memories, those stay altered. The power can fail if the mind of the target views the memory that was implanted as "unnatural" or "strange".

Comment: First of all, welcome to the site. Second of all, you're going to need to define how this magic works for us to be able to provide any reasonable answer.

Comment: okay i will edit it

Comment: @DarkYagami Specifically, let us know if he needs touch, line of sight, or if he can just change anyone. What memories can he change? Are there defenses against it? How many people can he affect in a day? Are there other people that have this ability (that he knows of)?

Comment: "Nobles" sounds like you have a specific time in your head. I would be interested in knowing when this is happening and if there are important differences to our current society.

Comment: hey guys ive changed it, does it sound more answerable to you?

Comment: @Secespitus it's in our time. Society is a bit more prude, and discrimination is still a huge part of it.

Comment: "one person in one moment" - does it mean that artificial memory will disappear after the contact is broken, or just that he has to build his "network" one person at a time?

Comment: @Alexander, I am curious of this too.  I did it with the assumption that it would remain, but did make a note that if he does lose the memory, enough natural memory should be created by then so that that loss memory will just seem like a brain fart.

Comment: @Alexander Oh no, the memory still remains. He can use it on several people, he just can't do it at once.

Comment: Can he alter memories to ANY extent or does he have to budget a reserve of power? And what counts as touch/ eye contact/line of sight? Does duration or amount matter?

Comment: Is there anything that could stop him from, say, running around touching/looking at everyone in sight until one by one most of the city has been altered?

Comment: Dang! I used to know the answer to this...

Answer (score 4):

So for this to work, he would need to do some prep work himself.  He would need to find a noble with a decent amount of political pull.  Bump into him a few times walking around.  Walk past him so he sees you.  This will establish that he knows you from some where.  When you go to implant a new memory, it won't seem foreign because you already established a natural memory.

Once you plant a memory, you use your connection with him to get into places otherwise would be VIP restricted.  Political parties, political events, invites you tocome with him to dinner parties of higher ups.  Use him to gain natural networking for other people with more influence.  Once he has served his purpose, you go on to the next person who holds more political say and whom you have become close with.  Plant a memory that you are someone of importance and have him then vouch for you as he takes you around doing the same thing.

The only catch that we don't know is if when he switches people, does the memory then fade?  Even if that was true, he should still retain the natural memory you created with him and he will just think it's a brain fart and he forgot about that moment in time.

Once he has gained enough noble and political support, it should be fairly easy for him to then make a move and gain highest political prestige!

Comment: the memory doesn't fade it still remains. the only way a memory fails or goes away, is if the memory appears to be too strange to the victims mind.

Comment: @DarkYagami Yes I saw your comment which is good cause I built my answer around the assumption that the memory would remain :)  Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: youre welcome. i sometimes forget imporant things

Answer (score 3):

Well, one method would be for him to start trying to pit the higher ups against each other so he can rise up by making each of them think that the others are starting to conspire against them, making certain people forget things like dates, deadlines, etc. (this can cause a lot of chaos by making people unable to coordinate, but do it too often and they'll get suspicious and/or start writing things down more often), and/or by inserting little memories making himself look more trustworthy. The key point would be for him to have answers that don't seem too convenient (or to change the minds of anyone who thinks he does) to all the problems his memory tampering causes and for him to portray himself as being overall more competent, but not blatantly out for their jobs.

This is definitely a long term strategy though, so if you need him to get into power quickly, you probably should choose something else.

Comment: o god imagine what some one like little finger could do with this sort of power.

Answer (score 2):

Since it only affects one person at a time, he would definitely have to use it sparingly, and on important people. Make them think they agreed to meetings, agreed to donate to his campaign, agreed to place him in important positions.

Also, is there a way he could possibly *create* something, or have something created, that would help him use it for mass hypnosis? Then, at rallies and such, he could plant memories in the crowd's minds of his opponents saying and doing horrible things, and make them think they had planned to vote for him all along.

Of course, all of this only works in a voting society, and since you mentioned nobles, I'm not quite sure that's what you have. If it's *not* a voting society, and it's the king, or nobles, who decide things, then he could work on them in much the same way. To counteract the "will-reject-if-memory-seems-strange" part, he could maybe alter memories a little at a time? Like, he can't just make the king think he promised to hand him the throne, 'cause that would be weird, but he *can* make the king think, slowly, that his heirs are untrustworthy, that the only one who *can* be placed on the throne is this fellow....

Those are just my thoughts, I hope they're helpful to you :)

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways for your protagonist to rise up. For example, he can work his way into the royal palace (shouldn't be too difficult with his power), and once there, make an eye contact with the king. Then he would plant a memory that the king had a long-lost son, and he is this son.

Comment: Queens born children always between witnesses, these witnesses were normally the most powerful and the most prestigious  people of the country. Later they watched the crown prince regularly. It was done to avoid any problem about the identity of the king. There were a lot of similar problems, as "lost crown princes" were "found", and of course they wanted the throne, it was against this. They toke it so serious that even the English king family has did it so until 1982.

Comment: Note: the permission to take part in the birth of a new crown prince was an extremely big gift from the king, and it costed for him nearly nothing. And the king wanted to have as many friends as possible, his power depended on them. Thus, it often happened that the queen couldn't easily give birth because there was such a terrible crowd in the hall where it happened. Everybody wanted to see the birth of a new king, and everybody wanted to say later in his life, that *"As our most beloved king X has born, I was there in the hall"*.

Comment: Of course my recipe of coming to power is simplified. The manipulator would have to affect other people beside the king to make it work smoothly.

Comment: I think becoming a king were too dangerous. Many of these powerful people who had seen the birth, were the leaders and other important members of the most powerful noble families. They knew very well, that a king family lives "forever" and owns the throne "forever". The chance for their family to step to the throne, doesn't surely happen in every century. And a switch in the ruling family means mostly civil war. This was the reason, why politics affected so deeply the marriages in the medieval era, they were needed to stick the country together and to avoid the wars.

Comment: About the topic :-): I think it would be much better to change the remembers of *many* people, but only a *little bit*, as to change the remembers of a few people greatly. Power is mostly about the agreement, a lot of people has to agree that you are a kings main advisor, or similar. Also I think it is better on this way to become some powerful man in the shadows, as to be a not always very powerful, but very well known man. Modifying the memory of others is highly unnatural, and thus it can result highly unnatural consequences even on indirect ways.

Comment: Such an indirect way is, for example, [Rasputin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grigori_Rasputin)'s fate. He wasn't a memory modifier, he was only a tricky cheater, but he could become the advisor of the Tsar (russian king). But he wasn't very strong in the politics, thus the powerful nobles has cooperated against him and killed him.

Comment: Of course, becoming "man in the shadows" is another good way of gaining power. My example of becoming a crown prince is just one that is probably most quick and straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Memory manipulation is a power with great power to destroy people's lives, and advance your own.  Consider:

- As a child, your greatest competition in school is given false memories about the things he is learning, and fails an important test.  Even if they learn they were wrong, it's too late to fix.
- At a more subtle level, being able to make someone remember something real in a slightly different way can affect the way that person perceives you.  Suddenly you are trusted as a humble, kind, and generous person, when you are none of the sort.  Friends are easy to come by.
- Later in life, anyone you perceive as a threat (or even as serious competition) would be vulnerable to accusations from people with false memories.  They could be thrown out by a spouse for adultery, or even falsely convicted of crime.
- If you want to commit a crime yourself, it becomes trivial to set someone up as your alibi with this power.  And even if you were caught and imprisoned, you could probably convince your jailer that you were improperly jailed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to go a different way from the other answers and say that, in addition to influencing powerful leaders, one of the most important things is being able to **touch and make eye contact with as many people as possible on as regular a basis as possible.**

Does your city have an entrance gate? DMV-type citizen registration system? Regular census? If not, use your pull on the most influential people in government to make this the case, and make them make YOU the person in charge of it.

If you want ultimate micromanaging control, here's the best strategy I can think of:

1. Use your power to convince the top doctors and officials in the country that there is a horrible disease going around and that the only way to contain it is for everyone in the city to get **treatment involving an eye exam at least once a month** (or whenever the government tells them to).
2. Make them **put you in charge** of this! You're amazing and the most capable person they know! In fact, remember when you handled that other amazing thing that was just like this? Well, now they do.
3. Set up a system where **you can look into the eyes and touch anyone who you want** on a regular basis, or on demand. If you want to make it look really legit, you can have a bunch of lackeys that "examine" the people you don't care about, while reserving the really important people for yourself.

The key is being able to not just modify memories once or twice, but to constantly keep them up so that no one gets suspicious. You will be limited only by speed with which you can modify their memories, and perhaps being able to keep track of whose memories belong to whom.

By convincing people they were really sick before they saw you and feel better afterwards, you can set yourself up as the hero and sole savior of the new world.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

The power can be used to ensure he is given credit for major successes and is seen as the fair recipient of benefits, by courts, powerful people, and so on.

In most countries, power is closely related to money, and those who don't have large-scale power already, may gain it through their money and business influence, this seems a good place to start. Also it means he doesn't need to influence many people, or obviously, which is going to play to his strengths.